Trouble understanding the proof that $(4,x)$ is not the power of a prime.
Background
Show that $(4,x)$ is primary ideal of $\Bbb{Z}[x]$ but is not a power of any prime ideal of $\Bbb{Z}[x]$.

If $(4,x)$ is the power of a prime ideal $P$ then $P$ must contain $(4,x)$.  But $\Bbb{Z}[x]/(4,x)\backsimeq \Bbb{Z}_4$ and so the only possibility is $P=(2,x)$ which corresponds to $2\Bbb{Z}_4$, the only proper non-zero ideal of $\Bbb{Z}_4$.  However, $(2,x)^n\neq (4,x)$ for any $n\geq 1$.

Questions
In the above solution, at the end where it says "However, $(2,x)^n\neq (4,x)$ for any $n\geq 1$."  Is the reason that $(2,x)^n\neq (4,x)$ is as follows:  Since $(x,y)=(x)+(y)=\{x\cdot f_1(x)+y\cdot f_2(x)\mid f_1(x), f_2(x) \in \Bbb{Z}[x]\}$, where $(x), (y)$ are both elements of $\Bbb{Z}[x]$, and for $n=1$, let $(4,y)=\{4\cdot m_1(x)+y\cdot m_2(x)\mid m_1(x), m_2(x) \in \Bbb{Z}[x]\}$, $(2,y)=\{2\cdot n_1(x)+y\cdot n_2(x)\mid n_1(x), n_2(x) \in \Bbb{Z}[x]\}$.  Then $(4,x)\nsubseteq (x,2)$ since $\frac{2}{4}\cdot n_2(x)\not\in \Bbb{Z}[x]$.
Thank you in advance.

Say $R$ is a commutative ring with $1$ and $I=(a,b)$ is an ideal generated by $a,b\in R$.
Let us look at what $I^n$ looks like:
An element in $I^n$ is a finite sum of terms with form $\alpha_1\cdots\alpha_n$ with $\alpha_i\in I$, i.e. $\alpha_i=ax_i+by_i$ for some $x_i,y_i\in R$.
Hence $\alpha_1\cdots\alpha_n=(ax_1+by_1)\cdots(ax_n+by_n)$ is $R-$linear combination of $a^{n}, a^{n-1}b,\cdots, ab^{n-1}, b^n$.
Therefore $I^n\subseteq (a^{n}, a^{n-1}b,\cdots, ab^{n-1}, b^n)$.
Obviously $(\supseteq)$ also holds for the above equation.
Hence $I^n=(a^{n}, a^{n-1}b,\cdots, ab^{n-1}, b^n)$.
Now we return to the original problem:
by the previous observation we have
$$(2,x)^2=(4,2x,x^2).$$
$$(2,x)^3=(8,4x,2x^2,x^3)  $$
$$\cdots$$
Can you conclude $(2,x)^n\ne (4,x)$ for all $x$?

@Asugab sorry I just saw your answer today.  I think $(2,x)^n\ne (4,x)$ because $(4,2x,x^2)\not\mid 4$ and simiilarily $(8,4x,2x^2,x^3)\not\mid 4$ etc.  Is that correct?

@Seth Well, $4\notin (2,x)^n$ if $n\ge 3$, but $4\in (2,x)^2=({\color{violet}4},2x,x^2)$. But you can argue $x\notin(2,x)^2$: if $x=4f_1(x)+2xf_2(x)+x^2f_3(x)$, what can you say about the coefficient of $x$ of both sides?

for the case of $x$ on both sides $2xf_2(x)=x$ which imply $1/2\not\in \Bbb{Z}$?

@Seth That is OK. A more direct way is, say coefficient of $x$ in $f_1(x)$ is $a$, and the constant term in $f_2(x)$ is $b$. Then by comparing the coefficient of $x$ on both sides, we conclude $1=4a+2b$, which is absurd since $2\nmid 1$ but $2\mid 4a+2b$.

what about for $n=1$, then $2\in (2,x)$ but $2\not\in (4,x)$?  If $2\subseteq (4,x)$, then $(4,x)\mid 2$ which imply, $2=4g_1(x)+xg_2(x)$.  Since $\text{deg }(2)=0$ then $\text{deg }(4g_1(x)+xg_2(x))=0$.  Let $g_1(x)=a, g_2(x)=b$, then $2=4g_1(x)+xg_2(x)=4a+xb$.  I am getting the same thing as your solution.  But maybe I am mixing up some directions?

@Seth Say $2=4g_1(x)+xg_2(x)$. If $a$ is the constant term of $g_1$ then $2=4a$ with $a\in\mathbb{Z}$, which is absurd. By the way your solution is not quite correct because you can not directly assume $g_1,g_2$ are constant polynomials (they may have higher degree terms $a_nx^n$).

if I can't assume that $g_1, g_2$ to be constant polynomials, what can I assume about them?  i feel like this question's method of solution is very similar to showing that $(x,2)$ is not PID in $\Bbb{Z}[x]$.  Is that correct?

@Seth We only know they are in $\mathbb{Z}[x]$: $g_1(x)=a_nx^n+\cdots+a_1x+a_0$ for some $n\in\mathbb{Z}_{\geqq 0}$ and $a_i\in\mathbb{Z}$. The same for $g_2$.

I am going to think about this some more.  If I am still have difficulties, I will let you know here, if that is ok with you. I think I am just not seeing this with the right perspective for now.

@Seth OK. Please let me know if you still have confusion. My comments have given a complete proof for $(2,x)^n\ne (4,x)$ (by casework $n=1$ and $n\ge 2$). You may read them and then see if you are still confused.
